# Make WEB Api calls from Application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api, asp.net-web-api

I posted few days ago this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487141/make-local-web-api-call-from-local-web-forms-app) and I was able to test the application just fine from a local environment.

Today I published the API at this [location](http://web2.mindsetworks.com/API). For some reason the calls I was able to do locally, for example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5832/api/Cage",
            data: JSON.stringify({ ssqUserId: 176650, token: 'b2fwfybdeec177hespp7orvvzvf0rv', ssqEventId: 1, baitUsed: '1', baitPlaced: '12/12/2016', cageFell: true, clickOnCageToClose: '05/01/2016', successfulOrNot: false })
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

Was working fine in local environment and I was able to save the data correctly.

But when I'm changing the URL to

> url: "http://web2.mindsetworks.com/api/Cage",

In the ajax call I'm not able to get anywhere.

In the local environment i had cors enabled with this line of code above the controller declaration:

> [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:15528", headers: "*", methods:
>   "*")]

I removed that line of code in order to open the API online. Do I need to do anything else in order to access the remote API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you deployed your application to a sub-directory of your domain `http://web2.mindsetworks.com/API`.

This, of course, causes your Web API application to have the following entry point:

```
http://web2.mindsetworks.com/API/api
```

The controller you mentioned is reachable at this URI:

```
http://web2.mindsetworks.com/API/api/Cage
```

---

As an aside: if you want to allow CORS for any domain you have to configure it using your `HttpConfiguration` object and providing to it a default instance of the `EnableCorsAttribute` that uses wildcards:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding your route twice

```
routes.Add(new Route
( "MS_attributerouteWebApi",
     "Category/{action}/{categoryName}"
     , new CategoryRouteHandler()
));
```

Second time, you are adding at line number 128

```
SSQ_Api.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +128
```

Comment: actually I was testing something in my appllication last 5 minutes, please try now, I reverted back to the initial state.

Comment: A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

Comment: You can directly check your API URL in the browser to see your error